# Что делает этот код? (Ассемблер)

Tags: c++, ассемблер, таймер

В коде, где тестируется работа таймеров SDL2, обнаружил следующий код:

```
int asmFunction (void)
{
    static int internalValue = 1;

    #ifdef __GNUC__
    __asm__ ("movl %0, %%eax\n\t"
        "add %%eax, %0"
        : "=r" (internalValue)
        : "r" (internalValue));
    #elif _MSC_VER
    _asm {
        mov eax, internalValue
            add internalValue, eax
    };
    #endif

    return internalValue;
}
```

Вместе с запуском программы включается таймер на 15 секунд, а по прошествии времени вызывается следующая функции, и программа корректно завершает работу. Как установить таймер - мне понятно, но вызов функции с ассемблером мне не ясен:

```
Uint32 repeatOnceFunction (Uint32 interval, void * param)
{
    SDL_Event exitEvent = { SDL_QUIT };
    if (asmFunction() != 0)
    {
        SDL_HideWindow (static_cast <SDL_Window *> (param));
        SDL_Delay (15000);
        SDL_PushEvent (&exitEvent);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При удалении вызова этой функции работа таймеров не меняется, разве что программа завершается резко по окончанию таймера, без паузы. Что же делает этот код?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ассемблер в данном случае просто осуществляет приращение переменной на её собственную величину:

```
movl %0, %%eax
add %%eax, %0
```

Помещает переменную `internalValue` в регистр, а затем прибавляет к нему значение `internalValue`. Так как `internalValue` статична, получается следующее:

```
asmFunction() // 2
asmFunction() // 4
asmFunction() // 8
```

*Как справедливо заметил @avp, на системе с четырехбайтовым целочисленным, код будет выполнять условие `!= 0` только 31 раз, последующие итерации будут возвращать 0 из-за переполнения:*

```
movl %0, %%tax ; 1000...0000 (-2147483648)
add %%eax, %0  ; 0
```

> В коде, где тестируется работа таймеров SDL2, обнаружил следующий код

Нет, это не код, где тестируется таймер SDL2. [Это кусок лабораторной работы](https://github.com/i582/HLProgramming).

> Что же делает этот код?

Исходя из описания этой работы — вводит вас в заблуждение. Плюс, выполнение полной версии кода `repeatOnceFunction` из моей ссылки приведет к крашу, так как колбек таймера будет выполнен не в UI потоке. Скорее всего для этого и заморочки с `asmFunction()`, а исправление выглядит как-то так:

```
static int internalValue = 0;
```

Comment: Вообще-то, этот ассемблерный код 31 раз вернет не 0, а потом будет возвращать 0. Не программируя в винде, не знаю, как там в целом будет работать вся программа

Comment: Согласен, будет переполнение. Дополню ответ.